# Simple example of a caffe python input layer (for images with labels)

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

The requirement is that the python script be more illustrative than performant.

1. Keep it simple (no multiprocessing, that can be a separate step)
2. It should take-in images and corresponding labels in batches of 50.
3. It should apply the `transformer` (resize, transpose, mean, raw-scale, channel swap) to each image in the `setup` step.
4. The rest of the network can be a caffe bvlc reference network or Alex net. It could be something *simpler* if it can better demonstrate that the network in working fine, end-to-end.
5. In effect, the python layer should work as if the images and labels are being provided by `type: "ImageData"` (which takes in a text file with image path and label)
6. As a simplification, no validation code is required.

From the unit-test provided [`here`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_python_layer.py), my thought is that the `setup`, `forward`, and possibly `reshape` code needs to be "filled" in (no `backward` code needed). My assumption is that the `forward` will process images in batches of 50 with a get_next_batch function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is already available!

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pascal-multilabel-with-datalayer.ipynb

with the pyhton input layer code here,

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pascal_multilabel_datalayers.py

Sorry to cause consternation about why this was asked (I got dinged for asking).

The question is legit. Just needed to look harder.

Could help someone later.